# How to retrieve an array of post IDs by a particular value stored in a custom meta's array

Tags: query-posts, post-meta

I have a custom post type 'projects' that has custom post meta 'members'. 'members' stores an array of another custom post type's IDs.

I'd like to do loop through the 'projects' posts that have a particular member ID in the array of the project's post meta.

Hope this made sense!

Apologies that I'm not better formatting asking questions here.

Comment: If you need to query on data, it should ideally not be stored in an array.

Comment: I can store it in a comma delimited string as a single string value. Can I query a substring? ... e.g. get all the posts that have value "32" in a substring of one of its post meta data

Comment: Maybe you show code you already have to achieve your goal?